# How to use graphs in Foxx?

Tags: arangodb, foxx

I have created a graph in ArangoDB. It is possible to access the graph from Foxx?

I can create graph in following way:

```
var graph_module = require("@arangodb/general-graph");
var graph = graph_module._create("myGraph");
```

But there is not a method to load graph from ArangoDB to Foxx.

Answer (score 2):

You can load the graph using the `_graph` function:

```
graph = graph_module._graph("myGraph");
```

The code works the same in arangosh and in Foxx.

It's also described in the documentation:
https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/graphs/general-graphs/management/#load-a-graph